# Jersey (REST) throw exception and map to HTTP error or return custom error code?

Tags: rest, exception, jersey

Basically I written a REST service and my business logic requires me to validate the input. For instance make sure the format of phone number is (###)###-####. If it is not, it should return invalid phone number. Further more I need to record all actions of the service. So when the client queries the system, they can find out what was the last action. I.e:

ACTION: ADD - SUCCESS
ACTION: ADD - INVALID PHONE NUMBER

So now I'm thinking whether I need to create my own custom error codes or just use the default HTTP ones and also record those inside the "log"

Pretty new to REST style so if my logic is off let me know...

So should I...

```
public void callPerson(String phone)
{
    try
      validate(phoneNumber)
      call person
    catch
        throw Invalid Phone Number
    finally
       record status to DB
}
```

or

```
public myStatusCode callPerson(String phone)
{
    try
      validate(phoneNumber)
      call person
    catch
        return myStatusCode
    finally
       record status to DB

}
```

In fact I also want to make sure the status gets recorded as well other wise it would not be good if say the action worked but the status update didn't. So updating the status should really be part of the "transaction"

Also another thing to keep in mind this REST service some of the actions have to communicate with an older "message" oriented service where the response and error code are in the XML response message...

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a HTTP status code 412 (Precondition Failed) and a String message for the error.

Comment: Cool! And I suppose REST clients can easily read this? I'm used to more of a message oriented service pre SOAP where both request and response is XML. So apart the fact that the client gets HTTP 200 OK for the response they also need to parse the XML response and get the status codes of the system. And additional information that they requested.

Comment: The status code won't be in the XML body. REST resources produce 3 things 1. a representation (XML encoded or other) 2. headers (cache, security...) 3. a status code. Every client is capable of getting this 3 informations. In Java, Jersey offers `response.getStatus()`, `response.getHeaders()` & `response.getEntity(Person.class)`. Looking carefully, you will notice that Jersey do the unmarshalling for you ; **you don't have to parse the response**.

Comment: Ok well what if the the client is an application and it wants to store the 412 (precondition failed) "Phone Number invalid" into a database for audit purpose. getStatus() will return 412 how will I get the "phone number invalid" value.

Basically I'm looking to create a very lightweight XML web service without the heaviness of SOAP etc... REST seems right but now I'm stuck using HTTP error codes I canot map my own etc...

Comment: Yes, REST seems right for your purpose. response.getEntity(String.class) is enough to get the message of a 412. In some cases, error messages are embedded in object, its up to you.

Comment: Ok, getting the hang of this so you are saying I can either return HTTP 412 - Phone Number Invalid or return HTTP 200 with message body including custom code? Or HTTP 412 with message body containing custom code?

Comment: HTTP 412 with message body: `return Response.status(Status.PRECONDITION_FAILED).entity("Invalid phone number").build()`

Comment: I'm creating very message oriented service without the heaviness of SOAP. And I have 100s of "error" codes. So I have to see best option of how to map everything and if I just want to use POST for everything...